# Nesting Jasper expressions

Tags: grails, groovy, jasper-reports

I have a field (`$P{ORDER}.permit`) which is `Integer` (0,1) and I'd like to display it as a `String` ("No", "Yes"). So I added below keys to `ResourceBoundle`:

```
order.permit.0=No
order.permit.1=Yes
```

I wrote expression `$R{order.permit.$P{ORDER}.permit}` but it doesn't work. An exception is thrown

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Too many groovy classes were
>   generated. Please make sure that you don't use Groovy features such as
>   closures that are not supported by this report compiler.

I suspect that this exception is caused by nesting jasper expressions or nesting them in wrong way.

How should I write the expression to achieve desired result?

**EDIT: `str("order.permit." + $P{ORDER}.permit)` is the answer. Details in the below post.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str()` instead of `$R{}`.

See also http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=54665:

> $R{} and str() are largely the same thing.  The functional difference
>   is that $R{} can only be used with fixed/static keys, while str() can
>   be used with dynamic message keys, e.g. str("message.prefix." +
>   $P{message}).

Comment: Thank you, `str("order.permit." + $P{ORDER}.permit)` is the answer!